FFMPEG unexpectedly stops any stream
I am trying to stream my webcams (32+ pcs) with
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -v verbose -rtsp_transport tcp -fflags +genpts -i "{SOME RTSP URL}" -c:v copy -an -threads auto -f hls -hls_time 3 stream.m3u8>nul 2>{SOME LOGFILE}

to web via HLS. But ffmpeg stops randomly and unexpectedly after 1-3 min of working. Why can this happen?
With 1 cam the same outcome. However, ffplay with many cameras working perfectly.
Here's the log:
size=N/A time=00:14:56.63 bitrate=N/A speed=0.966x    
size=N/A time=00:14:56.63 bitrate=N/A speed=0.965x    
size=N/A time=00:14:56.63 bitrate=N/A speed=0.964x    
size=N/A time=00:14:56.63 bitrate=N/A speed=0.964x    
size=N/A time=00:14:56.63 bitrate=N/A speed=0.963x    
size=N/A time=00:14:56.63 bitrate=N/A speed=0.963x    
size=N/A time=00:14:56.63 bitrate=N/A speed=0.962x    
[hls @ 0000021423bf8580] Opening '{SOME PATH}\stream89.ts' for writing
[hls @ 0000021423bf8580] Failed to open file '{SOME PATH}\stream89.ts'
[vost#0:0/copy @ 0000021425ed0400] Error submitting a packet to the muxer: No such file or directory
    Last message repeated 1 times
[out#0/hls @ 0000021423bfd880] Error muxing a packet
[out#0/hls @ 0000021423bfd880] Task finished with error code: -2 (No such file or directory)
[out#0/hls @ 0000021423bfd880] Terminating thread with return code -2 (No such file or directory)


Get rid of -f hls -hls_time 3.  Use -f rawvideo -pixel_format yuv420p and match -pixel_format to the incoming stream.

For testing, I recommend you to try streaming from localhost: 1. Install and execute mediamtx. 2. Stream synthetic pattern to localhost: ffmpeg -re -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=384x216:rate=10 -vcodec libx264 -g 10 -pix_fmt yuv420p -rtsp_transport tcp -f rtsp rtsp://localhost:8554/mystream. 3. Execute command from localhost, and check if the issue is reproducible: ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -v verbose -rtsp_transport tcp -fflags +genpts -i rtsp://localhost:8554/mystream -c:v copy -an -threads auto -f hls -hls_time 3 stream.m3u8>nul 2>log.txt

Note: -fflags +genpts is probably not required. In case of realtime HLS streaming, consider cyclic list of files (add -hls_list_size 10 for example). Check the following answer for example. The error Failed to open file could be related to writing permissions, or full disk.

Nothing helped(( Maybe should I use GStreamer?
